# Parsing variables in context.bot.send_message()

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm currently developing a bot with the help of [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and I've encountered myself with a bit of a problem.

See the goal is that when the user runs the command **/casosspain** the bots answers with a number which previously selects from a database and saves on a variable. Lets call it **var**

```
var = "12.321.231"

def casosspain(update, context):
context.bot.send_message(
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
    text="Los casos confirmados en españa son: "
)
```

I tried with **print(var)** after the *text=""* declaration but it doesn't work since its a positional argument after a keyword argument.

My goal is to print out this line:

```
Los casos confirmados en españa son: 12.321.231
```

Any ideas on how could I make that work? Would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's f strings [7.1.1. Formatted String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

```
text = f"Los casos confirmados en españa son: {var}"
```

```
>>> var = "12.321.231"
>>> text = f"Los casos confirmados en españa son: {var}"
>>> print(text)
Los casos confirmados en españa son: 12.321.231
```